# SCSS / CSS responsive curved border

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

I am trying to make a responsive curved border with scss / css (using ionic 3) for an android app and is meant to look something like this:

[image: What the border is meant to look like]

PS: it would also be really nice if the curved section can be easily resized to any height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach :

```css
#background {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: tomato;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}

#background::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 200vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50vh;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="wrapper">Some content above the background element</div>
```

Comment: does the basic thing it's meant to do, but any content i add in div#container stays behind the :after (the curve)

Comment: I edited my answer... I hope this helps even if it's pretty straight forward. Did you experiment or searched for this ?

Comment: Nice! it works!! thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `:after` pseudo element for blue part and set `overflow: hidden` on parent.

```css
.el {
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #B5B5B5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.el:after {
  content: '';
  background: #48B2FF;
  height: 150%;
  width: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="el"></div>
```